# Processing A CSV With Every Line Wrapped In Double Quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, double-quotes

Oh boy, my first Stack Overflow question! One of our clients is sending us a CSV file to process, but the way they're sending it, every single line is wrapped in double quotes:

```rb
"example, header, values\r\n"
"example, first, line\r\n"
"example, second, line\r\n"
...
"etc, etc, etc\r\n"
```

This in turn is causing Ruby to parse every line as a single field, including the headers, which is causing this data ingestion script to crash.

The code currently opens this as a `File` object, which then gets passed to a `CSV.foreach` enumerator with some configurable `options`:

```rb
CSV.foreach(<File Object>, <Options Hash>).with_index(1) do |line, index|
# process a record
end
```

**Is there a straightforward way to tell Ruby to just ignore these quotes so that it can correctly parse individual fields?**

I've tried changing the `quote_char` in the CSV options to a single quote, but somehow that actually makes things worse. I could probably do all sorts of work to remove these quotes from the file before processing it, but that would require making a bunch of changes to legacy code, and I'd like to avoid it if I can. I've gone through [some documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) about CSV options, but I'm not seeing any obvious silver bullet.

For reference, the CSV options are configured as such:

```rb
{
 headers: true,
 skip_blanks: true,
 encoding: 'bom|utf-8',
 liberal_parsing: true,
 header_converters: lambda { |f| f.downcase.strip },
 row_sep: "\r\n",
 quote_char: "'"
}
```

Comment: My first solution would be to request the client to send you a properly formatted CSV file -- it's clear they are doing something goofy.  Failing that -- add a preprocess step that takes the original file and strips the junk off the ends of the rows and saves it as a proper CSV file.  Then the ruby CSV class will just work.

Comment: The way you have written your example suggests that there is an unseen line feed (`\n`) at the end of each line, following the second double-quote, possibly preceded by a Windows-supplied carriage return (`\r`). If you merely remove the two double quotes each line will end with `"\r\n\r\n"` (or `"\r\n\n"`). I presume you don't want that. Please clarify.

Comment: Well it seems like I'm learning a lot of valuable lessons with this ticket. @CarySwoveland you're correct I'd prefer lines to end with a simple "\n", but I should have dug in more when changing the quote_char option made things worse. I no longer believe the quotes are the problem, but rather that our client is sending us a malformed CSV to begin with. Digging into the file it looks roughly like this:
```
"id, header1, header2, header3\r\n"
"id, value1, value2, value3, value1 | value2 | value3\r\n"
```
We agreed they wanted pipe delimiters, and I think they're struggling with it.

Comment: You said it looks roughly like, `" \"id, header1, header2, header3\r\n\" \"id, value1, value2, value3, value1 | value2 | value3\r\n\" "`. (I have modified what you gave because single quotes cannot be used. Note `'\n'.size #=> 2` whereas `"\n".size #=> 1`.) There are 4 headers in the first line but 7 values in the second line. Please have another look at that. I have some code you might find useful but I need to modify it to correspond to the actual file structure. I suggest you provide a string that contains the header line followed by two lines with values. Best to edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do a little "pre-processing" on the file before parsing the csv. Like this:

```rb
#test.csv
"status,color,name\r\n"
"active,green,Norm\r\n"
"inactive,red,Herb"
```

```rb
# test.rb
require 'csv'

not_csv = File.readlines('test.csv')
real_csv = ""

not_csv.each{|line| real_csv += line.sub("\\r\\n","").gsub('"','') }

parsed_csv = CSV.parse(real_csv, headers: true)
puts parsed_csv[0]["status"] #=>active
puts parsed_csv[1]["name"]  #=>Herb
```

from the console run `ruby test.rb`

Comment: I'd be careful with `gsub('"','')` since there may be quotes in the actual data. I'd use some kind of regex like this `.sub(/(^")/, '').sub(/"$/, '')`, the actual solution may vary if OP needs it to work for correctly formatted CSV

Comment: @JanVítek yes that's a better method, thanks